# Passing the bearer token in yii2 rest returns an error of 401

Tags: php, rest, angular, yii2, typescript2.0

Am using angular2 and yii2 restful services but it fails

This is my angular2 part

```
In the userservice
 constructor(private http:HttpClientService, private _domaindetails:Domaindetails) { }

profile(val:string="profile"):Observable<User>{
return this.http.get(this.getUserUrl(val))
  .map(this.extractData)

 }
```

This is the httpclientService

```
 createAuthorizationHeader(headers: Headers) {
  let token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser")).token;
  if (token) {
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   }

  }

post(url, data) {
  let headers = new Headers();
  this.createAuthorizationHeader(headers);
 return this.http.post(url, data, {
    headers: headers
 });
}
```

This is my backend In Yii2

```
    public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
     $behaviors['corsFilter'] = [
        'class' => \yii\filters\Cors::className(),
        'cors' => [
            // restrict access to
            'Origin' => ['http://localhost:4200'],
            'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['POST', 'GET','PUT'],
            // Allow only POST and PUT methods
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
            // Allow only headers 'X-Wsse'
            // 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => true,
            // Allow OPTIONS caching
            'Access-Control-Max-Age' => 3600,
            // Allow the X-Pagination-Current-Page header to be exposed to the browser.
            'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => ['X-Pagination-Current-Page'],
        ],
    ];

    $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => HttpBearerAuth::className(),
        'only' => ['can-access','profile'],  //access controller
    ];

   $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];
    return $behaviors;
}
```

And the yii2 action fails returning an error of unauthorized access

```
 public function actionProfile()
{

    $user = Yii::$app->user->identity;
    return ['data' => $user];
}
```

When i check `Yii::$app->request->headers;`

[image]

As you can see the bearer token is set

This is my usermodel

```
   public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
{
    return static::findOne(['auth_key' => $token]);  //auth_key is the value used in bearer token
}
```

Why does it keep on returning an error 401 unauthorized access and yet when i use the same value of authkey and set authorization bearer headers in postman it works

After a few research i found out that the whenever angular2 makes a request it sends an options request which fails

Comment: Have you tried setting the behavior to "bearerAuth" instead of "authenticator"?

Comment: That also fails and returns unknown bearerAuth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who might face this problem i found out that this was caused by the HttpBearerAuth and when i changed to `QueryParamAuth` everything is now working i also made a few other changes as

```
ON THE CONTROLLER
1.Removed the cors filters

public function behaviors()
{
    $behaviors = parent::behaviors();

    $behaviors['authenticator'] = [
        'class' => CompositeAuth::className(),
        'authMethods' => [
            HttpBasicAuth::className(),
            HttpBearerAuth::className(),
            QueryParamAuth::className(),
        ],
    ];
    return $behaviors;

}
```

2,In my config main.php

```
     'response' => [
        'format' => yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        'charset' => 'UTF-8',
        'on beforeSend' => function ($event) {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        }
    ],
        'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => 'auth', 'pluralize'=>false],
            ...other controlers here
        ],

    ],
```

3.In the .htacess file in the project root i added

```
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type"
```

So my angular2 post request looks like

```
http://127.0.0.1/bcl/api/rest/v1/auth/logout?access-token=your access token
```

So the access token is always passed as a query parameter

The main reason is because i found out that if the browser sends any header apart from content type an options request is triggered

So now my headers look like

```
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); 
//i removed the bearer token
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a different approach:

Added

```
    public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        parent::beforeAction($action);

        if (Yii::$app->getRequest()->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
            // End it, otherwise a 401 will be shown.
            Yii::$app->end();
        }

        return true;
    }
```

in the controller.

**Keep the behaviours function as at your question**.

As you mentioned, the issue is that the browser sends a preflighted request.

My assumption is that you are making a cross browser request(localhost:4200), so the browser is making an OPTIONS request first to the server to find out the "Access-Control-Allow" settings, but without an access token in the header. So a 401 is thrown and the CORS process fails.

The difference is that this way, you can have the authorization token in a header.

Comment: I tried your method but fails i think the behaviours are executed first before even the beforeAction

Comment: Try to set  'Origin' => ['*']  in the behaviour() to allow all hosts. I see you did the same in your solution inside the config. Anyway this should match the angular host.